# Can a type-trait be made for promotions?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-promotion

I need to know when a promotion takes place, and what it is.  My guess is

```
template <typename T>
struct promoted { using type = std::common_type_t<T, T>; };

template <typename T>
using promoted_t = typename promoted<T>::type;
```

Obviously, this will break if the user starts overriding versions of `std::common_type`.  Assuming that doesn't happen, will it work?  The conditional operator is supposed to apply promotions before further evaluation.  I do think something like this should be in the Standard someday.

If you're wondering why I want this, it's for C-level varargs:

```
auto  r = va_arg( the_va_list, T );
```

If I originally passed in a type that gets transformed when used in varargs, like `float`s turning into `double`s, do I put in the original type for `T`, or the mangled type?  In case it's the latter, I'm making a traits-type for that, which needs the promotion trait in the last step.

Comment: I just realized I could manually use `decltype( declval<bool>() ? declval<T>() : declval<T>() )` instead of hoping that `common_type` isn't overridden. (You can override `common_type` if at least one type is user-defined.  Enumeration types are user-defined and can sometimes be affected by promotions.)

Comment: "The conditional operator is supposed to apply promotions before further evaluation" -- No, it isn't. That isn't even possible in C++, where the result of the conditional operator can be an lvalue.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, a `bool ? T : T` makes a `T`. Nothing gets promoted in that expression.

Passing a non-POD (or really, any user-defined) type in a C-style variadic argument list invokes undefined behavior.

MSC, for example, pushes a copy of the structure onto the stack without calling a constructor (if one is defined).

For example:

```
struct thing
{
    int v;

    // Not called
    operator int() const throw()
    {return this->v;}

    thing(int v) throw() :
    v(v)
    {}

    // Also not called
    thing(const thing &other) throw() :
    v(other.v)
    {}
};

void frob(...)
{
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    thing t(47);

    frob(t); // <- rep stosd/q here, but this is really UD

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

To clarify: It is not possible to use templates to detect something being passed into a C-style variadic argument list, as it is undefined what the compiler does with user defined types in such situations.

Comment: Looking at Section 13.6 [over.built], the promotion happened before that point.  For example, if I used `float`, the pseudo-declaration for "`bool ? T : T`" would already be `double`! That's what I want; I want to know if that could fail. It'll probably work for the integer types, but does it for enumeration types?

Comment: Now I'm somewhat confused... A `bool ? float : float` makes a `float`. Are you trying to determine what an enumeration type is promoted to? Perhaps the underlying type? An example of where this is a problem for you would help.

Comment: I want a type-traits for the promotions listed in Sections 4.5 [conv.prom] and 4.6 [conv.fpprom] of the Standard. I wanted them to make a type-traits for the mangling listed in Section 5.2.2 [expr.call], paragraph 7 (as of N3797). Of course, there should be Standard type-traits for both transformations, but I need it sooner.

Comment: For your only (as of this writing) comment, I just checked with a compiler website, and the conditional always returns the same type, even if it should have been promoted according to Section 13.6. I guess the compiler writers assume that not promoting the type is more useful. (Only geeks like me would care about promoted types.)

Comment: Standardese is very strange in this respect. The usage "promoted types" in 13.6 is just a convenient way to refer to a specific class of symbol (conventions of EBNF infecting the rest of the document), and is used to imply that promotion should only be performed when the two types of that operator don't match (a.k.a. 'widening', or picking the widest amongst L and R). In the case of two types being the same, no promotion is required (why promote a `float` to a `double` if no new information is being created? -- or to put it another way: `float` is technically a promoted type by itself).